# How to run msi files under Wine

Tags: linux, windows-installer, wine

Every time I try to run this program, it gives me this error.

```
czipperz@CzipperzComputer~/Downloads> msiexec /i Corsair-Utility-Engine-v1.3.91.msi 
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
```

I haven't seen any other solutions online. Could you guys help me out.

Comment: It seems likely that you'd need to make some improvements to wine's MSI support.

Comment: Or fix the MSI, if it happens to be open source.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a bug in wine 1.6: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.6/+bug/1383214

A fix has been recently released.

Answer (score 0):

.msi runnables are for the windows platform not linux, but you might be able to run windows applications on your linux device using WINE (WINdows Emulator).

But WINE is not an emulator it is a compatibility layer, meaning it "translates Windows API calls into POSIX calls on-the-fly" so it's faster than emulation.

P.S. This method doesn't work for all programs especially newer ones

Comment: The OP is already using Wine.  (I've edited the title to make that more obvious.)

Comment: Im just going to copy the program files stuff onto a flash drive from windows and put it back on linux

Comment: OK on WINE it says "This application failed to start because it could not fine or load the Qt platform plugin 'windows'.  Reinstalling the application may fix this problem."

Comment: Seems like ill have to emulate windows for this to work which is silly.